# How to improve the performance of the for loop in Pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 10000 columns and 3000 rows. I want to call the below function for each column and this is taking me 1+ min. I would like to reduce it, say 10s since the same code in Rust is just taking 1 sec to complete. I know python will not match Rust performance but a reduction is welcome. Is there something I can do which can vectorize or improve performance?

```py
def extract_cycles_v3(series: pd.Series):
    from collections import deque
    import numpy as np
    points = deque()
    result = []
    def format_output(point1, point2, count):
        x1 = point1
        x2 = point2
        rng = np.abs(x1 - x2)
        mean = 0.5 * (x1 + x2)
        return rng, mean, count
    for point in series:
        points.append(point)
        while len(points) >= 3:
            # Form ranges X and Y from the three most recent points
            x1, x2, x3 = points[-3], points[-2], points[-1]
            X = np.abs(x3 - x2)
            Y = np.abs(x2 - x1)
            if X < Y:
                # Read the next point
                break
            elif len(points) == 3:
                # Y contains the starting point
                # Count Y as one-half cycle and discard the first point
                result.append(format_output(points[0], points[1], 0.5))
                points.popleft()
            else:
                # Count Y as one cycle and discard the peak and the valley of Y
                result.append(format_output(points[-3], points[-2], 1.0))
                last = points.pop()
                points.pop()
                points.pop()
                points.append(last)
    else:
        # Count the remaining ranges as one-half cycles
        while len(points) > 1:
            result.append(format_output(points[0], points[1], 0.5))
            points.popleft()
    return result
```

Below is the time spent by profiler

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     9                                           def extract_cycles_v3(series):
    10      5625     200287.0     35.6      0.0      from collections import deque
    11      5625      31852.0      5.7      0.0      import numpy as np
    12      5625      49075.0      8.7      0.0      points = deque()
    13      5625      17245.0      3.1      0.0      result = []
    14      5625      32680.0      5.8      0.0      def format_output(point1, point2, count):
    15                                                   x1 = point1
    16                                                   x2 = point2
    17                                                   rng = np.abs(x1 - x2)
    18                                                   mean = 0.5 * (x1 + x2)
    19                                                   return rng, mean, count
    20   9241245   30028829.0      3.2      3.8      for point in series:
    21   9241245   30075819.0      3.3      3.8          points.append(point)
    22  13715870   49794814.0      3.6      6.3          while len(points) >= 3:
    23                                                       # Form ranges X and Y from the three most recent points
    24  13715870   55754712.0      4.1      7.1              x1, x2, x3 = points[-3], points[-2], points[-1]
    25  13715870  158680523.0     11.6     20.2              X = np.abs(x3 - x2)
    26  13715870  143759753.0     10.5     18.3              Y = np.abs(x2 - x1)
    27   9096216   25824510.0      2.8      3.3              if X < Y:
    28                                                           # Read the next point
    29   9096216   20523135.0      2.3      2.6                  break
    30   4577013   15633704.0      3.4      2.0              elif len(points) == 3:
    31                                                           # Y contains the starting point
    32                                                           # Count Y as one-half cycle and discard the first point
    33     42641    1982939.0     46.5      0.3                  result.append(format_output(points[0], points[1], 0.5))
    34     42641     182248.0      4.3      0.0                  points.popleft()
    35                                                       else:
    36                                                           # Count Y as one cycle and discard the peak and the valley of Y
    37   4577013  193884083.0     42.4     24.6                  result.append(format_output(points[-3], points[-2], 1.0))
    38   4577013   15812058.0      3.5      2.0                  last = points.pop()
    39   4577013   13912050.0      3.0      1.8                  points.pop()
    40   4577013   13846706.0      3.0      1.8                  points.pop()
    41   4577013   14957967.0      3.3      1.9                  points.append(last)
    42                                               else:
    43                                                   # Count the remaining ranges as one-half cycles
    44     38953     155899.0      4.0      0.0          while len(points) > 1:
    45     38953    1695531.0     43.5      0.2              result.append(format_output(points[0], points[1], 0.5))
    46     38953     157556.0      4.0      0.0              points.popleft()
    47      5625      14289.0      2.5      0.0      return result
```

[source](https://github.com/iamlikeme/rainflow/blob/main/src/rainflow.py)

Comment: can you share some input data?

Comment: Also can you explain the point of this function?

Comment: One quick point, `np.abs` is not necessary here. Just use `abs` like `X = abs(x3 - x2)` for example (change each time), you'll gain speed